# Why can't I run PHP after multiple methods of installation?

Tags: php, download, installation

I want to be able to code in PHP on my Windows 8 PC. I have attempted multiple methods of installing PHP and so far none of them have worked.

So far I have downloaded from php.net, used Web Platform Installer 5.0, and downloaded XAMPP. But every time I try to create a PHP file, the PHP code doesn't run.

How would I be able to download a version on PHP that actually works on my computer?

Comment: Do you get errors with the different versions (and if so, what are they?).

Comment: I have added paragraphs to your post to make it a little easier to read.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is good for beginner level, so I recommend going with that option for now. Then make sure that the server is up and running, that your files are in the `xampp/htdocs` folder, and that you are accessing them like so: `http://localhost/myfile.php`.

If this is not enough make sure to thoroughly read a guide on how to set up, [like this one](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/), and if that still doesn't solve it please come back with more details on exactly what you are trying and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using xampp, ensure that your document root is set to the webroot of your project. If your files aren't located in the xampp/htdocs directory, then you'll have to edit the document root in the httpd.conf file of the Apache directory (which is located in your xampp directory)